# Reverse DNS Server Can't Find NXDOMAIN Bind9

Tags: dns, bind9

I'm setting up DNS with Bind9, but I couldn't resolve the reverse DNS.

This is my **named.conf.local** file:

```sh
zone "alice-abm.id"  { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.alice-abm.id"; };
zone "190.193.116.in-addr.arpa" { type master; file "/etc/bind/db.190.193.116.in-addr.arpa"; };
```

This is my **db.alice-abm.id** file:

```sh
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     alice-abm.id. admin.alice-abm.id. (
                        2021112801      ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.alice-abm.id.
@       IN      NS      ns2.alice-abm.id.
@       IN      A       116.193.190.67
ns1     IN      A       116.193.190.67
ns2     IN      A       116.193.190.67
www     IN      CNAME   @ ;Bisa juga dengan alice-abm.id
```

And this is my **db.190.193.116.in-addr.arpa** file:

```sh
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     alice-abm.id. admin.alice-abm.id. (
                        20211128003     ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
$ORIGIN 190.193.116.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN      NS      ns1.alice-abm.id.
@       IN      NS      ns2.alice-abm.id.
@       IN      A       116.193.190.67
67      IN      PTR     alice-abm.id.
```

When I try to nslookup the IP Address:

```sh
$ nslookup 116.193.190.67
```

That's return errors:

```sh
** server can't find 67.190.193.116.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Is there any mistake I did?

Pleas help, and thanks.

Comment: "Is there any mistake I did?" That you are posting an offtopic question. Your question is not related to programming so is offtopic here. Besides that, for reverse DNS to work you need to get delegation from the company that gives you the IP addresses you use. You don't explain why you need reverse names (in almost all cases you don't need them), and if you are new to DNS that is not something you should try first.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your logs, but the serial number is supposed to be unsigned 32bit, and 20211128003 far exceeds it. I think you mean 2021112803. The zone is probably not getting loaded.

Unless you have full control of that /24, I would make the zone 67.190.193.116.in-addr.arpa

Comment: I have made it to 2021112803 but still not working. What should I do else?

Comment: Logs, what do the logs say? Has the ISP allocated that IP address to you? Is the glue setup? What does `dig +trace` show? Indeed, there is no glue.